# How multiple framework references works in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, architecture

I am new to iOS development, so please forgive for the termnology I'll use to explain my question.

My project architechture is like I have multiple WorkSpaces of multiple projects as follows

```
MyProjectModelWS
          -> BaseModelProject
               -> IMyMainProtocol
                    -> SomeMethod
          ->DerivedModelProject - References BaseModelProject
               ->MySampleClass Implements IMyMainProtocol
                    -> SomeMethod //Implementation goes here
MyProjectControllerWS
          ->MyControllerProject - References BaseModelProject and DerivedModelProject
               ->ControllerClass - this class uses methods of BaseModelProject and DerivedModelProject
```

I want to create Framework of each project in each workspace and publish them into a relative path.
Then I want to use them into different projects as needed.

Please suggest how should I manage this.
Thanks

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? You'll need to be much more specific.

Comment: The goal is to create separate WorkSpaces for Model, Controller and View in MVC pattern Each workspace contain multiple projects.

Lets say I have a workspace - WSModel witch contains MainModelProject and MyModelProject where MyModelProject references MainModel.

I need to create framework for each project separately.

MainModelProject's framework can be used in some projects of controller workspaces and MyModelproject in some others.

I am taking reference of each class from MainModelProject to MyModelProject to create independent framework.

Please suggest.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do. What I don't understand is where you're stuck. Which part are you not able to do? What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: I'm not stuck but just want to make sure am I on right path. My approach looks like complex management of multiple projects x multiple workspaces. Looking for something that is simple. I've just came into ios development from .NET (simple environment compared to xcode) so its different and new.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you likely to reuse the model and controller in other projects? In my experience, those tend to be fairly specific to a single app, though it's feasible they could be used in more than one project. If you're not going to re-use them, I don't see the point in putting them into their own frameworks. But if you know you'll use them in multiple projects, that would be a good way to do it. It's hard to say without more intimate knowledge of your projects, though.

Comment: You are right. We are going to use these modules in multiple apps or lets say these are common base for all of our applications.